# Unity3D build freezes unless mouse is moved

Tags: unity-game-engine, udp, background-process, pixelsense

I have a simple Surface 2.0 (PixelSense) application that sends UDP messages to my Unity3D game when there are touch events since Unity doesn't support .NET 4. When I run the game in the Unity editor everything works fine, but when I run the actual Unity build the game freezes unless I move the mouse (keyboard input doesn't unfreeze it). Once it unfreezes, all the updates happen at once.

I also tried running a simple unity build with a sprite that translates in the X axis and starts over once it's not being rendered (does not receive UDP messages). This build runs at the same time as the surface app so it's also running in the background and it also freezes unless I move my mouse so I don't think it's a networking issue.

Run In Background is checked and I also have it in the script.

```
private void Awake()
{
    Application.runInBackground = true;
}
```

Visible in background is also checked in the Player Settings.
I run the game windowed at full resolution.
Any ideas about this problem?